# Returning mulitple bools from a bit-wise field in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Our DB Admin is very old school, and thinks that storing multiple values in a bit-wise field is the best solution for things like email verified and phone number verified etc.. etc..

So I am trying to write a MySQL statement that will parse out the verification status as bool's into something more human readable, but I am having difficulty writing the statement. He's also away for 3 months so I can't contact him.

Here’s the definition of the bit flags in the `Users` table that are being used for email and mobile verification.

The `MiscFlags` is a `NOT NULL BIT(8)`, with a default `b'0'`

After digging through our docs I found these rules:

```
MiscFlags & 1 = 1      email has been verified
MiscFlags & 1 <> 1     email has not been verified
MiscFlags & 2 = 2      mobile has been verified
MiscFlags & 2 <> 2     mobile has not been verified
```

My statement:

```
SELECT  u.*,
        u.MiscFlags & 1 = 1   AS EmailVerified,
        u.MiscFlags & 2 = 2   AS MobilePhoneVerified
FROM Users u
WHERE u.id = 12345 LIMIT 1;
```

If an email is verified, it should spit out `1`, *I think*. I'm dealing with millions of records, so I'm unsure if I am getting the correct answers for people who DON'T have a verified email but a they DO have a verified mobile number.

Is my SQL statement valid? Are there issues with storing this, and possibly other "bools" in the manor? Can MySQL even index this type of field?

Comment: Why not setup a dummy table and create a few records in known states and TEST IT

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's a valid SQL statement. From what you have described, I expect it would give you the result you're looking for.

No MySQL cannot index a bitfield. At least it won't do what you think -- you can't index the selection of individual bits.

But you aren't searching for individual bitfield conditions, you're searching for a single row by its `id`. The `id` I assume is the primary key, which is an index. Once you've found that row, there's no need for another index. The projection of each verified bit is just evaluation of a single expression against a single row.

Comment: Thanks @bill-karwin I was looking to make sure I wasn't inverting the result or something odd. I don't use bit-wise very often.